The following error has occurred: Upgrade Failed due to the following Error. The error code is:-2147467259.Message: Unspecified error
I am trying to install Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313]
I tried to install it, and then after a few minutes i get this error:
The following error has occurred: Upgrade Failed due to the following Error. The error code is:-2147467259.Message: Unspecified error
Im not sure what the issue is, or if anyone is able to help as theyve had this issue before. thanks
